# Why has bidet use not spread to the northern countries of Europe?

Tags: europe, middle-east, italy, everyday-life

As wikipedia states, the [bidet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidet) is quite common in southern European countries (in Italy for example, it is found in 95% of households), in the Middle East and in East Asia. Conversely, bidets are quite rare in Northern Europe. Why the discrepancy in usage?

Comment: I guess because it is really unpleasant to sweat on your genitals (so it's not related t history). In colder climates sweating in general is less of a problem. I'd also risk a connected observation that we have less cultural preference towards perfumes and deodorants. On some occasions I've found them unbearably, and I mean UNBEARABLY, strong in southern countries.

Comment: As kubanczyk said, the question isn't really on topic. What does washing your anus have to do with History? However, you probably could change the question to something like, "What historical reason did the bidet..." That might work.

Comment: Based on the intimate knowledge of the area I gained from watching Crocadile Dundee movies, I'd say it isn't very common in Australia either. :-)

Comment: @Russell if a simple word-change trick makes it in-topic, then it was on topic even before.

Comment: So, it's putting the emphasis somewhere else. The first one had the emphasis on washing your anus and the form I suggested had more of an emphasis history. To use a coding analogy (not that I'm qualified :) ), it doen't matter where you put the pointer astrix, but it definitely helps readability.

Comment: It's a valid on-topic question that I'd like to know the answer to as well. Most modern inventions with high adoption rates in any of the first world countries bathrooms tend to spread around the globe. The bathroom tends to have the same technologies around the world, including the toilet, the sink, the shower, and toilet paper. The bidet is an invention adopted by entire first world economies like Japan and Italy but is mysteriously missing from other countries that have the money to afford them but choose not to. The reason to not adopt is entirely related to history.